# VBA - Conditional Formatting with tick mark and x mark

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, conditional-formatting

So, I am trying to use these symbols from conditional formatting, but I only need the red x and green tick mark.[image: symbols]  Is there a way to use only those two with conditional formatting and apply it within my code.

For those that have answered this is what my screen looks like.[image: edit formatting]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you are applying you conditional formatting you could just set both to green then the last one to red as the picture show, when the number is greater equal than 0 is green else red. ( It's the italian excel version but i think that you can understand what i did)

[image: Conditional Formatting]

[image: No middle simbol]

Comment: I have edited my post to show my edit formatting rule

Comment: changed the image, should work like that, i have Excel 2016, you can't change icon in your excel version but it should work

Comment: I have Excel 2007, So, I cannot get rid of the middle symbol?

Comment: No in the conditional formatting window, but you get rid of it setting both, yellow and green to the same value, only green will be show. You can accomplish the same thing (without setting value for the yellow circle) using vba, but i do not recommend.

Answer (score 2):

See this:

Note the comparison operators with values. For **Yellow** select `>` instead of `>=`.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Go to CF menu.
- Manage Rules
- Edit Rule
- Select ! and pick "No cell  icon"

Comment: I have edited my post to show my edit formatting rule